# In what ways could or couldn't having students do homework in $\LaTeX$ for extra credit be helpful for them at the college level? High school level?

Tags: secondary-education, homework, latex

Do you think having students turn in homework in $\LaTeX$ say for extra credit is helpful for them at the college level? At the high school level? There could also be a few assignments that have to be in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: See answers and comments to [How should LaTeX be taught to university students?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/504/745) AND [Should LaTeX be taught in high school?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18275/745)

Comment: While I think that this is an interesting and useful discussion to have, it doesn't quite fit with the SE format, which expects that questions should have authoritative, objectively correct answers.  There are some questions which are kind of borderline which may be acceptable (e.g. "How do you implement TeX instruction at the college level?"), but questions which ask for opinion-based discussion are generally off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that one should *allow* submitting homework, etc. in $\LaTeX$, perhaps, one can even go as far as encouraging it, but *demanding* it will be way overboard.

In my humble opinion, if your subject and class format do not strictly require working on a computer or knowing how to program, then there is no reason why you should assume that the students have either the equipment, or the necessary skills. If they can handle pen and paper, they should be already qualified to get into such a class assuming they have completed all necessary prerequisites. The new technology should *give new opportunities*, not *enforce new restrictions*. Whether to use those opportunities or not should be left to the user to choose.

Comment: In the US, I think it is *absolutely* fair to assume that students have access to the necessary equipment.  I don't know that I have ever encountered an American institution of higher learning which does not have computer labs and libraries with computers for student use.  *Many* institutions also have laptops which students can check out (either by the hour, or by the semester).  And, presumably, the goal of assigning LaTeX'd homework is to *teach* them the skills they need (and learning the tech creates new opportunities).

Comment: I would also point out that there are a *ton* of students who show up on Math SE with zero TeX skill, and managed to figure out how to format their questions using only the rather terrible "crash course" which is provided on the meta.  I don't think that the bar to entry here is all that high, and instructor provided templates plus Overleaf should make it quite accessible.  I don't find your arguments very convincing...

Comment: @XanderHenderson *"In the US, I think it is absolutely fair to assume that students have access to the necessary equipment."* If you've read our discussion with Dominique (which is deleted now, probably for better), you should be able to see that some people might disagree with you here. As to "teaching $\LaTeX$ in the course", I strongly prefer to stay on teaching the *course subject*, though I have nothing against offering the students the *optional* $\LaTeX$ training in my and their *free* time and I've done such things (about something else that I thought would be useful) in the past :-)

Comment: @XanderHenderson And yeah, most mathematically inclined people can learn basic $\LaTeX$ in no time, but I have a friend in economics (quite a prominent guy in social choice theory), who is absolutely incapable of it (don't ask me why) and still uses scientific word (or something like that) instead.

Comment: I don't see any deleted discussion with anyone (there are no deleted comments here...).  In any event, your answer seems to say "No, don't teach LaTeX because (a) students might not have access to the technology and (2) students my not be skilled enough to use the technology."  I don't think that (1) is generally true, and (2) seems condescending to me.  In your reply to me, you have added a third argument, which is that you only want to teach the "course subject".  I have no issue with this as an answer, but it isn't one of the arguments you have given in your answer.

Comment: I'm also curious to know how you would respond to a history instructor requiring that all student work be typed.  If, as you say, students lack access or skill, is it unfair to demand that students turn in typed work?  Is it unfair to expect a certain citation style *in* that typed work?  Students are often very confused by different citation styles, and learning the "correct" style isn't the "course subject"---by your argument, history profs should accept hand-written work with whatever kind of citation students can muster.  I don't know many history profs who would agree...

Comment: @XanderHenderson I would respond in the same way. Yes, handwritten work with *readable* handwriting and correct spelling should be accepted.  As to "whatever kind of citation", one can insist on a certain *standard format* (author,title, journal, year, pages or whatever that is in history), but not on typing it in certain fonts, etc. As to disagreement, it is everybody's undeniable right. I'm just voicing my opinion and telling what I would or would not do and why, but I have no means to enforce it at my disposal.  :-)

Comment: @XanderHenderson *"I don't see any deleted discussion with anyone"* Not here. In the thread about lending calculators. * *"(2) seems condescending to me"* Hah? Some students in my low level classes have trouble adding fractions! It is a fact that there are people who don't have certain skills and need a lot of effort to acquire them. I'm not "feeling more important or intelligent than them" (the primary meaning of "condescending") *just because of that*, but yeah, I *do* have some skills other people don't (and other people have some skills I don't have too).

Answer (score 0):

In the Age of Information, but before the Age of AI, it seems like it would be very helpful for the students--especially since we have Overleaf and don't have to download a whole editor. Learning a neat type-setting language, maybe even some programming that could be helpful for future employment. Having a neat organized solution to a problem to read. The only problem is they can use ChatGPT, and while it is not great at math, it is great at programming, so it seems code can be copied. Though, prompting the $\LaTeX$ code would still be non-trivial as you must type in your solution for ChatGPT and there will still be several follow-ups.